# NoSuchMethod exception in MultiAutoCompleteTextView Android

Tags: android, android-logcat, multiautocompletetextview

I am fetching all contact through the following function .

```
public ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> getAllPhoneContacts() {

        Log.d("START","Getting all Contacts");
        ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo> arrContacts = new ArrayList<PhoneContactInfo>();
        PhoneContactInfo phoneContactInfo=null;     
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID}, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            String contactNumber= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));  
            String contactName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            int phoneContactID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));

            phoneContactInfo = new PhoneContactInfo();
            phoneContactInfo.setPhoneContactID(phoneContactID);             
            phoneContactInfo.setContactName(contactName);                   
            phoneContactInfo.setContactNumber(contactNumber); 
            if (phoneContactInfo != null)
            {
                arrContacts.add(phoneContactInfo);
            }
            phoneContactInfo = null; 
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }       
        cursor.close();
        cursor = null;
        Log.d("END","Got all Contacts");
        return arrContacts;
    }
```

THen I have set adapter to MultiAutoCompleteTextView by the following code :

```
phoneContactInfo = getAllPhoneContacts();



    adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.list_item_for_new_message,R.id.contactName ,phoneContactInfo);

            autoCompleteTextView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchAutoComplete);
            autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

            autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

But I am getting the following exception :

```
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, class android.webkit.WebView]
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:562)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at com.mobvista.sdk.m.a.f.b.o(ProGuard:338)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at com.mobvista.sdk.m.core.MobvistaAd.init(ProGuard:43)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at com.pinguo.camera360.PgCameraApplication.onCreateByMainProcess(PgCameraApplication.java:329)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at com.pinguo.camera360.PgCameraApplication.onCreate(PgCameraApplication.java:227)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4579)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
12-01 11:34:21.204: E/DeviceUtil(5993):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why I am getting this error ? How can I solve this ?

```
12-01 11:50:54.451: E/ActivityThread(9137): RuntimeExceptionjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.commlink.messaging/com.commlink.messaging.New_Message}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class MultipleAutoCompleteTextView
```

My xml layout is as following

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <MultipleAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/searchAutoComplete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="To (Search by number or name)"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect" />

        <View
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
             android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Type message"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/send_message" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have no class named PgCameraApplication.java .

Comment: when you face this error.. i mean on which step?

Comment: Is `com.mobvista.sdk` your app package?

Comment: No , com.mobvista.sdk is not my app package .

Comment: @SagorAhmed: then share your application logs only instead of other crash logs from device. posted not is not useful to detect issues in current code

Comment: i cant understand your issues . ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: post your xml also , check this ` Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class MultipleAutoCompleteTextView `

Comment: I have posted xml layout file .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check it carefully you have created object for `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

```
autoCompleteTextView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchAutoComplete);
```

and in your xml you are writting it as `MultipleAutoCompleteTextView`

```
<MultipleAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/searchAutoComplete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:hint="To (Search by number or name)"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect" />
```

How will this work? There is no class in `Android` called `MultipleAutoCompleteTextView` change it to `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`